# Mysterious flickering icon on the top left corner

Tags: windows, windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

[image]
The double arrow is what I'm talking about.
I use a laptop running windows 10 with an Nvidea discrete card and I believe it started happening when I made it the default card on all programs. Any idea what it actually is?

I just noticed that when that icon flickers, there's another trailing the mouse:
[image]

The first icon appears regularly if I press and release the control key as well.

Comment: That looks like the scroll wheel for your mouse.  I have no idea why it would show up though.  Some scroll wheels can click left and right in addition to normal scrolling.  That would be my guess as to why there are arrows on each side.

Comment: It's a laptop and I don't have a mouse plugged in. The symbol makes little sense as the page in question couldn't even be side scrolled. It tends to happen when I hover clickable content but that might just be placebo.

Comment: you can still scroll with a pad right?  It may not have a physical wheel, but there is a scroll functionality built in to the touch pads.  They may have just chosen that image when you are able to scroll.

Comment: Yes, but the scrolling icon appears when I'm using my mouse as well. So it's just weird and I'd just like to know what it means.

Comment: It's a laptop and I don't have a mouse plugged in.  2 minutes later.... scrolling icon appears when I'm using my mouse as well.

Comment: I was just saying it doesn't seem to be related to the mouse. I'm currently don't have a mouse plugged in and both icons appear when I disable the scrolling capabilities of the touchpad.
These icons have been appearing for several months and just today my curiosity took the better of me and I decided to see if anyone knew what they meant.